# How can I assert that the jest mocked module method was called?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

How can I assert that the jest mocked module method was called?

E.g. in my .spec.js I have the following jest mocked module:

```
jest.mock('../../../../services/logs.service.js', () => ({
    log: jest.fn()
}));
```

Now I would like to assert the log method. I.e. something like this:

```
//the log was called twice with the text "foo"
expect(log).toHaveBeenCalledWith(2, "foo");
```

But I can not access the `log`. I tried putting the log initialization outside the jest mocked module, like so:

```
const log = jest.fn();
jest.mock('../../../../services/logs.service.js', () => ({
    log
}));
```

But I got the error:

> The module factory of `jest.mock()` is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables.

Comment: You import the test double _in the tests_, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

JavaScript

```
import { log } from '../../../../services/logs.service.js';

jest.mock('../../../../services/logs.service.js', () => ({
    log: jest.fn()
}));

expect(log).toHaveBeenCalledWith(2, "foo"); // JavaScript
```

TypeScript

```
import { log } from '../../../../services/logs.service.js';

jest.mock('../../../../services/logs.service.js', () => ({
    log: jest.fn()
}));

const mockedLog = log as jest.MockedFunction<typeof log>;

expect(mockedLog).toHaveBeenCalledWith(2, "foo");
```

Comment: It says `Type assertion expressions can only be used in TypeScript files.`. My file is .js, not .ts. Is there a way to do the same for .js?

Comment: Just ignore the TypeScript stuff. It is only there for TypeScript users.

Comment: It says `Parsing error: Unexpected token as`. I cant ignore it, the tests will not run until the errors are fixed.

Comment: I've edited the answer to have both JavaScript and TypeScript versions. Does that help clarify things?

Comment: Note there's no value to `mockedLog` in this case, and it can much more easily be created where you _do_ need it (i.e. where you want to access the methods that mocks have but the real implementation doesn't) with `const mockedLog = jest.mocked(log);`

Comment: Good point @jonsharpe. Leaving it in for reference.